# Angular DI skip until reach top level

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an input component which looks for `FormGroupDirective` via Angular DI and it works fine until I have one more FormGroupDirective.

In other words I can have something like this

```
FormGroupDirective
--> input 1
--> input 2
--> input 3
```

These inputs find this directive successfully, however if I add one more directive

```
RootFormGroupDirective
--> FormGroupDirective1
    --> input 1
```

input 1 retrieves `FormGroupDirective1` instead of `RootFormGroupDirective`.

I know that there is a `@SkipSelf()` decorator, however this one is not suitable in this situation since input component may be wrapped in an infinite number of components.

> Is there a way to skip this `FormGroupDirective1` when there is one more on higher level, or get the parent directive of this?

I found only how to get parent `FormGroup` but this on doesn't have `submitted`.

Comment: please help me on this @Sergey [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468510/angular-rows-edit-store-values-in-array#

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple and not obvious. You should not use more than one FormGroupDirectrive in on form. If we look at FormGroupDirective in API there is a row in `path` which says

> Returns an array representing the path to this group. Because this directive always lives at the top level of a form, it always an empty array.

Meaning that FormGroupDirective should be the only one. My mistake was that I was trying to pass my formGroup instances down by tree using `@Input() formGroup` which interfere with directive what caused the problem